# Cannot Redirect After HTTP POST nodejs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to do a HTTP POST of some input data from a HTML form to mongodb.
Although I am able to perform the database insertion of my data but unable to redirect to another HTML page after the operation is finished.
I have tried both `res.render` as well as `res.redirect`, but nothing seems to work.
However,  I am getting a successful `post /index 200` followed by a `get /home 200`.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

On the front side maybe write something like this

```
 $.post("/").then(function(data) {
    window.location = data.redirectUrl;
});
```

And in the server side write this

```
 res.send({err: 0, redirectUrl: "/"});
```

Comment: this *is not* the pattern you would use in angularjs;